# Программно открыть балун метки, которая находится в кластере

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть список меток, которые были добавлены в кластер. В интерфейс есть сам список этих меток, на карте метки объединены в кластеры, в сайдбаре интерфейса -- обычный список линейный список.

Пользователь кликнул на элемент этого списка, мы узнаем id точки, затем ищем эту точку в кластере, и если ее нашли, делаем зум на нужный кластер, чтобы точки этого кластера отрисовались на карте, а затем делаем вызов балуна на "кликнутой" точке.

Возможно ли это реализовать, с учетом, что метки объединенные в кластер не отрисовываются физически на карте?

Comment: Зачем вы всё усложняете? Зачем вообще кластеризация, если на карте ничего не будет отрисовываться до выбора конкретного объекта? Работайте с геоОбъектами и objectManager напрямую - как будет выставлен нужный зум и выбрана метка из списка, включайте её балун.

Comment: На карте будут отрисованы все метки, просто балун будет показываться над той меткой, которая была выбрана в сайдбаре. 

P.S. Таковы требования заказчика.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из комментария вам должен подходить пример из песочницы Яндекса про [балун для объекта кластера](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_balloon_open/) с дополнительным зумом на нужные координаты при выборе объекта примерно так:

```
var selectedObject = 5
var coords = geoObjects[selectedObject].geometry.getCoordinates()
myMap.setCenter(coords);
myMap.setZoom(13);
```

Сначала надо зуммировать (если требуется), потом уже выполнять процедуры из примера, поскольку кластеры на новом масштабе пересоздаются.

Comment: Примерно таким образом и сделал. Только как понять, что зум в 13 единиц будет достаточным чтобы кластер раскрылся на все содержащиеся в нем метки? Я сейчас зум делаю на 19, чтобы гарантировать это. Есть ли какая-то возможность, получить значение зума, для того, чтобы кластер раскрылся?

Comment: В том примере Яндекса есть строка if (objectState.isClustered) {... Как по мне, тут можно по положительному результату выполнять увеличение зума на единицу и проверять повторно, пока не станет FALSE. А уже в этом случае выполнять открытие балуна.